# Auto open Chrome web inspector for all pages

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I need to trace redirect using network tab, but it works only if I open web inspector and then reload page. Unfortunatly, I open this page from external native program and need to found, which URL is passed to browser. Is it possible to do this? I bneed to do this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible. The complete list of up-to-date chromium command line switches can be found here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

I thought you might be able to to get something working using `--wait-for-debugger-children`, giving you enough time to open the developer tools before the page loads, but setting that flag also gives the developer tools a 1 minute delay before loading.